# Polymer build not to create bundled and unbundled folder

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

I don't know why `polymer build` not create `bundled and unbundled` folders without giving any errors.

```
info:    Clearing build/ directory...
info:    (default) Building...
info:    (default) Build complete!
```

**polymer.json**

```
{
  "entrypoint": "index.html",
  "shell": "src/good-app.html",
  "fragments": [
    "src/good-home.html",
    "src/good-list-item.html",
    "src/good-data.html",
    "src/lazy-resources.html"
  ],
  "sourceGlobs": [
   "src/**/*",
   "data/**/*",
   "images/**/*",
   "bower.json"
  ],
  "includeDependencies": [
    "manifest.json",
    "bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Which version of `polymer-cli` do you use? In new version `0.18` you need to add some attribute like `--bundle` to create bundled folder for your files cause by default it create only one  `default` folder. Try to list all awaliable options by typing `polymer help build`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Starting in `polymer-cli` v0.18 you can add "builds" to polymer.json.

```
"builds": [{
  "name": "bundled-es6",
  "bundle": true,
  "js": {"minify": true, "compile": false},
  "css": {"minify": true},
  "html": {"minify": true}
},{
  "name": "unbundled-es5",
  "bundle": false,
  "js": {"minify": true, "compile": true},
  "css": {"minify": true},
  "html": {"minify": true}
}]
```

https://www.polymer-project.org/2.0/docs/tools/polymer-cli#build